# Customize list views with sharing settings in salesforce

Tags: listview, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

Is there any way where you can the list views in custom component with SHARING SETTING enforced using apex ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you are looking for but even in custom controllers you can still enforce sharing setting using with or without sharing class definition.

From documentation:

"Like other Apex classes, all custom controllers run in system mode. Consequently, the current user's credentials are not used to execute controller logic, and the user's permissions and field-level security do not apply.

You can choose whether a custom controller respects a user's organization-wide defaults, role hierarchy, and sharing rules by using the with sharing keywords in the class definition. For information, see “Using the with sharing, without sharing, and inherited sharing Keywords” in the Apex Developer Guide."

Links to the articles:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.222.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm